# VS 2010 Generate local resource, why does it check out the web.config?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Why when I generate local resource does it check out the web.config.  I've done a comparison after the process has completed and the web.config hasnt changed.

I'm using TFS 2010 Basic.

It's not a big issue but I would be interested if anyone knows the answer.

Cheers
Tigger

Answer (score 0):

What source control system you are using and what is the IDE plugging for that? ( e.g. SVN/Ankh) I have expereienced this before with MS TFS that it's client recognizes a checkout even if I go and do a save on the file without doing any changes.

[This](http://www.screencast.com/users/Zeus/folders/Jing/media/37b93334-9060-41a0-b648-abbb03326068) might help you if that is TFS

There is a same sort of question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221873/tfs-2008-checks-out-code-automatically-on-edit).

Comment: Hi Bumble Bee, I'm using TFS 2010 Basic.

Comment: I don't think they answer my question, unless i'm missing something.  When I perform the action of generating local resources files e.g., Tools ->Generate Local Resource the web.config (totatly unrelated file) is checked out.

Comment: Yes, but it could be that the Generate Local Resources tool saves the web.config for some reason. Let me check on that and let you know if I find anything.

Comment: what happens if you ask it not to check-out when saving? as per here (http://www.screencast.com/users/Zeus/folders/Jing/media/37b93334-9060-41a0-b648-abbb03326068)

Comment: That's what i want to know why would Generate Local Resource want to edit/save the web.config.